# Firebase Swift - Slow response - Rules index [g]

Tags: swift, performance, firebase, mapkit, firebase-security

My app is sending and retrieving large amount of data from Firebase every second, performing multiple functions.

I'm trying to understand the Firebase rules.  Currently I have the default rules set up.

```
  {
  "rules": {
  ".read": "auth != null",
  ".write": "auth != null",
  ".indexOn": ["g"]
    }
  }
```

However, in my debugger it is saying...

```
    [FirebaseDatabase] Using an unspecified index. Consider adding ".indexOn": "g" at /gameUserCoordinates to your security rules for better performance
```

Should I be creating something extra in my FireBase rules for gameUserCoordinates?
It is set up FirebaseRoot -> gameUserCoordinates -> UID -> GeoFireCoordinates

My user has to sign in and be authenticated to use the app.

Thanks, any help would be much appreciated.

UPDATE

```
var dbRef: FIRDatabaseReference {return FIRDatabase.database().reference()}

var gameUserCoordinatesRef: FIRDatabaseReference {return dbRef.child("gameUserCoordinates")}

func geoFireUploadUserCoordinates(latitude: CLLocationDegrees, longitude: CLLocationDegrees) {
    let userKey = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid
    let geoFireUser = GeoFire(firebaseRef: gameUserCoordinatesRef)
    geoFireUser?.setLocation(CLLocation(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude), forKey: userKey)
```

Comment: Without seeing your corresponding data structure (the JSON as text, no screenshots please) and the code that triggers this warning, it is hard to say anything more concrete than the error message already does. You'll find that you get the best help when you provide the [minimal, complete code/JSON/rules that reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: This is really two totally separate questions. Please focus on one question per topic and the first half of the post is unrelated to the second half and really should be removed. Also, 'removing functions once they are not needed' would be a odd practice so you are probably going the wrong direction on that one. There must be a specific reason you are using dynamic variables - do you need it for Obj-C runtime? If not it's probably unnecessary.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for responding.
Yeah I went off in a tangent regarding the first part, I've removed this from my question and kept the Firebase index[g] question.  
To answer your question it was for an annotation change - and the dynamic var seemed to solve the problem as it wasn't updating before.

I've added the data structure for the userCoordinates.
It appears that it is a suggestion to implement this [g] index.  I have the error message above (debugger part).  Thats all it says really.